# inter-AppDomain communication and interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, marshalling, appdomain

I am looking for a way to isolate a component (based on a 3rd party dll) in a separate AppDomain that can be unloaded. My plan was to use `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` and `MarshalByRefObject`-based objects for communication with the component.

The problem is that in order to use objects derived from `MarshalByRefObject` in the main assembly it has to reference the component dll and I am trying to avoid that. I thought I might decouple it via an interface

```
class MyObject: MarshalByRefObject, IMyObject
{
}
```

but I cannot cast the object returned from `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` to `IMyObject` (because it is actually a proxy, not a real object I guess?).

Am I missing something, or this just can't be done and the only answer is WCF?

Update:
The actual issue that I had was that IMyObject was defined twice: I had the file included in the main assembly and in the component assembly. This way I get an exception "Unable to cast transparent proxy to type". When I am using only one interface/class definition that I reference from both assemblies, it works fine (both as Will suggested and as I described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, interfaces kinda suck anyhow.

Ditch it and go with an abstract base class that inherits from MBRO.

```
public abstract class MyObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    protected MyObject() : base() {}
    public abstract void LoadPluginAssemblyLol();
    public abstract void ExecuteSuperCollider();
}
```

Pull that back across the boundary and control the plugin that way.  Also, remember not to expose events on the type (event subscribers get pulled across boundaries without you realizing it) and you should probably only take method arguments and have return values that are primitives or strictly controlled so that you don't accidentally end up with the dll loaded in your main domain.

Another issue you'll run into is that you have to manage the lifespan of objects that are proxied via an **[ISponsor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.lifetime.isponsor.aspx)** implementation.  Otherwise the instance in the host domain gets collected after 10 minutes.

As for using MyObject, you would...

// assume an implementation such as 'class MyObjectImplementation : MyObject {...}'

```
var type = typeof(MyObjectImplementation);
var newDomain = CreateNewAppDomainKthx();
var controller = newDomain
    .CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        type.Assembly.FullName, 
        type.FullName) as MyObjectImplementation;
controller.LoadPluginAssemblyLol();
controller.ExecuteSuperCollider();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I could do that but how do I create MyObject, via CreateInstanceAndUnwrap somehow?

Comment: Well, using the type e.g. `typeof(MyObjectImplementation)` implies I would need to reference the component from the main assembly. I tried `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(..., "MyObjectImplementation") as MyObject`, and it seems to work fine. I found an issue with my projects, and after fixing it the interface also works fine now. ISponsor shouldn't be an issue in my case, but very useful to know, thanks again.